# Parsing xml and selecting just specific positions from an array

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, listbox, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an xml document, that is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
....
    <maj>true</maj>
    <data>
        <c>2</c>
        <t>0</t>
        <r>168</r>
        <r>La rentrée Auchan</r>
        <r>0</r>
        <r>2012-08-21 00:00:00</r>
        <r>2012-08-28 00:00:00</r>
        <r>56</r>
        <r>VL</r>

        <c>2</c>
        <t>1</t>
        ...
    </data>
```

I want to get what there is inside the array "r", but only the first position 1 the position 5 and 6, and only where t=0
I've tried to work like this, I have a listbox that bind the data :

```
XDocument XMLtxt = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(e.Result);

listClients.ItemsSource =
    from c in XMLtxt.Descendants()
    select new JsonB()
    {
        t=c.Element("t").Value.Where(x=>(int) x==0), 
        r1=c.Element("r").Select(..
    }
```

the jsonB :

```
 public class JsonB
 {
     public int c { get; set; }
     public int t { get; set; }
     public string r1 { get; set; }
     public int r5 { get; set; }
     public string r6 { get; set; }
     public object[] r { get; set; }
 }
```

I really need help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML is a bit ill-structured, so you will have to fix this first with your code.. For starters, in a simple way you can sequentially read/parse the contents so that the structure of the record is clear, and then filter them:

- prepare a `list` of JsonB objects - name it i.e. 'allRecords'
- prepare a variable of type `JsonB` - name it i.e. 'lastRecord'
- prepare a variable of type `int` - name it i.e. 'numberOfRs'
- get the `<data>` tag
- loop over all of its direct `children`, and for each child:

  - check the name of the child
  - if it is `<c>`:

    - create new JsobB and put it into `lastRecord`
    - reset the `numberOfRs` to zero
    - add the `lastRecord` to the `allRecords` list
    - read the `c` value and put it into `lastRecord.c`
  - if it is `<t>`:

    - read the value and put it into `lastRecord.t`
  - if it is `<r>`:

    - add 1 to the `numberOfRs`
    - if `numberOfRs` is 1, 5 or 6:
    - read the value and put it into `lastRecord.r1` or r5 or r6

this way, you will have a list `allRecords` with pretty objects, and you can simply `.Where(item => item.t ==0)` on it.

However, you may notice it to be very 'wasteful' if many of such objects are to be ignored. Then, you could adjust the sequential parser to filter then on-the-fly and thus behave like this

- prepare a `list` of JsonB objects - name it i.e. 'allRecords'
- prepare a variable of type `JsonB` - name it i.e. 'lastRecord'
- prepare a variable of type `int` - name it i.e. 'numberOfRs'
- **prepare a variable of type `bool` - name it i.e. 'isInteresting', preset it to false**
- get the `<data>` tag
- loop over all of its direct `children`, and for each child:

  - check the name of the child
  - if it is `<c>`:

    - **if `isInteresting` is true**

      - **add the `lastRecord` to the `allRecords` list**
    - create new JsobB and put it into `lastRecord`
    - reset the `numberOfRs` to zero
    - <strike>add the `lastRecord` to the `allRecords` list</strike> **reset the `isInteresting` to false**
    - read the `c` value and put it into `lastRecord.c`
  - if it is `<t>`:

    - read the value and put it into `lastRecord.t`
    - **if it was zero, set the `isInteresting` to true**
  - if it is `<r>`:

    - add 1 to the `numberOfRs`
    - if `numberOfRs` is 1, 5 or 6:
    - read the value and put it into `lastRecord.r1` or r5 or r6
- **if `isInteresting` is true**

  - **add the `lastRecord` to the `allRecords` list**

This way, you will end up with a list that is already filtered and all not interesting items will be GC'ed in the meantime. Please note that the 'isinteresting - add to list' is done twice: once before creatig new JsonB, and then also in the final step when all children has been read. If you forget about the check-add after the loop - you may sometimes accidentially skip/ignore the last record.